# Spacing in a subscript

Tags: spacing, subscripts

I have a question about spacing in a subscript.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}
  $k\in I$
  
  \[\sum_{k\in I}\]
\end{document}
```

And here is the result :
[image: bad spacing]

As you can see, the I in the subscript of the sum seems sticked to the `in` symbol and I don't understand why. I think the problem comes from the newtxmath package.

Edit: I thank you all for your answers. So, there may be a problem with newtxmath. Does anyone know how I could contact the package's maintainer (Michael Sharpe)? There is no email, in the package documentation

Comment: Note that fonts use the same minimal space, here it is jsut very noticable because of the upright `I` comming from `frenchmath`

Comment: Indeed, the spacing is wrong also in text style: the space around `\in` looks very asymmetric.

Comment: Is it a bug in newtxmath?

Comment: Your code can be boiled down further to `\documentclass[frenchmath]{article} \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} \begin{document} $k\in I$, $\scriptstyle k\in I$ \end{document}`. The lack of space between `\in` and `I` looks likely to be due to a problem in the font's kerning table. Until the package's maintainer fixes the problem, replacing `k\in I` with `k\in\,I` when it occurs in first-level subscript positions might be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I don't want to add a thinspace because when the package's maintainer fixes the problem, i will have to delete all theses thinspaces. But I don't know how to contact him (Michael Sharpe)

Comment: So, no one to tell me how to contact the package's maintainer (Michael Sharpe)? I see that he is registered on this website. Maybe there is an option in the newtxmath package that I should use?

Comment: There is his email there: https://www.ctan.org/home/msharpe

Answer (score 5):

I've gotten in touch with the author of the `newtx` font packages, and he has confirmed that the spacing of `\in` is indeed a bug.

The problem is not limited to subscripts, and it has nothing to do with `frenchmath`, although it is more obvious when there's an upright letter.
The problem has actually been there for a long time, and the author is "really surprised that hadn't been picked up before."

He promises to submit a correction ASAP, and gave me permission to report his response here.

He also pointed out that his address is at the end of the README, and will consider adding it to the documentation file as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, Barbara. This is great news. I will wait for an update. Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I do not know how to do it on professional level of coding but my variant always work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}


\[\sum_{k \in\text{ }I}\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: might be easier using `\:`, `\ ` (backslash with a space after it) or `\,`

Comment: Ok, but I don’t understand why I should do that. The spacing should be good without anything more. And the spacing seems good without the newtxmath package