# Bad spacing with newtx?

Tags: spacing, newtx

I have a problem with spacing. I think the problem comes from the package newtx.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
  $\underbrace{1+2-3}_{=0}$
\end{document}
```

The 0 seems to be too near the equal sign. If I uncomment the two lines of newtx, the spacing seems better

Answer (score 6):

The `=` has a very tight bounding box in NewTX. In what follows I use `{=}0` in order to show the tightness also in text (or display) style.

Note that the sidebearings in Computer Modern are not that big, but the difference is noticeable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt\fbox{$=$}}

${=}0\quad\underbrace{1+2-3}_{=0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the `newtx` lines, I get

[image]

As you see, relation spaces are not added in script style. In this case I think it's good practice to add the `\;` space manually.

```
\underbrace{1+2-3}_{=\;0}
```

[image]

Another possible solution is to add some sidebearing to `=`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\widereq}{\mkern0.5mu\equals\mkern0.5mu}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`=\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\widereq
\mathchardef\equals=\mathcode`=
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`=="8000 }

\begin{document}

{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt\fbox{$=$}}

${=}0\quad\underbrace{1+2-3}_{=0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the problem is that I have been using newtxmath for not so long, and I have many math documents with just _{=0}. I can’t do what you suggest in all my documents. For the future ones, ok, but for the old ones …

Comment: I had already created a topic about spacing with newtxmath : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617156/spacing-in-a-subscript?noredirect=1#comment1541284_617156. And you had answered that the spacing was wrong.

Comment: @Didier I added the images and took the occasion to show an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you again, @egreg. Unfortunately, I am not sure I understood correctly your answer (I am French). Is the spacing _{=0} normal? Your first suggestion is to add \; manually. But in your image, the spacing seems very big, but maybe it is normal? What I don’t understand is why LaTeX doesn’t handle correctly the spacing in scriptstyle, and why I should add a \; manually. And didn’t you reverse the first two images? Because with newtxmath the spacing is narrower with my documents but it is the opposite in your images. And your second suggestion is way beyond my understanding

Comment: I also have the same problem with >0, …

Comment: In my previous topic (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617156/spacing-in-a-subscript?noredirect=1#comment1541284_617156) Barbara Beeton had managed to contact the author of the package because there was a bug in spacing. Maybe another bug?

Comment: @Didier TeX adds no space around binary relations when in script style. If you deem `\;` too big (and I may agree), use `\,`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. I’ll try that